# Scaling Jenkins setup using Apache-Mesos and Marathon

Tags: linux, jenkins, mesos, marathon

I need some high level recommendations/steps from those who have already done this work. I need to scale my Jenkins to handle large number of jobs with minimal effort and configuration. I came to know that we can use Mesos and Marathon for this purpose.

Can some come up with high level steps for doing this ? Also , comment what plugins do i need to install and what is their stability level ( Any known bugs or problems ) ?

My Current Environment:

`Centos7` , `Puppet,Foreman` , `Jenkins` , `Openstack Virtual machines as Jenkins slaves`

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already considered Mesos and Marathon for this, might I suggest also looking at DC/OS (which builds upon Mesos and Marathon)? My team at Mesosphere maintains the Jenkins package for DC/OS, which includes many plugins to get you up and running quickly: https://github.com/mesosphere/jenkins-dcos

You might also find the jenkins-mesos mailing list helpful: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jenkins-mesos